# Facebook graph api /comment breaking whole program

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Am, building an application which would post comments on users birthday wish post, but,the problem is with comment graph api, the statement is executing once and the whole application is breaking up, I did debug with echos, and its the same, no code is executing after the one comment. please help

```
<?php

    require 'src/facebook.php';


    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => '',
        'secret' => ''
    ));

    $app_url = "https://apps.facebook.com/appleappspace/";
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
<head>
<body>

    <?php
            if(!$uid){

                $params = array(
                     'scope' => 'user_birthday,user_friends,friends_birthday,friends_status,
                                read_stream,email,status_update,publish_actions',
                     'redirect_uri' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/appleappspace/'
              );
                $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'> top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
            }else if($uid){
                        try{

                            $strings = array("b'day","birthday","bday","hbd","bdae","Birthday");    

                                 echo "Successfully Logged In <br/>";

                            $yesterday = mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")-3,date("Y"));

                            $yesterday = date("Y-m-d",$yesterday);

                                $user_wishes = $facebook->api('/me/feed?since='.$yesterday,'GET');
                                $length_user_wishes = count($user_wishes['data']); 
                                $string_length = count($strings);
                                 for($i=0;$i<=$length_user_wishes;$i++){    
                                    for($j=0;$j<=$string_length;$j++){
                                           if(strchr($user_wishes['data'][$i]['message'],$strings[$j]) !== FALSE){
                                           $POST_ID = $user_wishes['data'][$i]['id'];
                                           $comment = "Its not Working";
                                          $facebook->api('/'.$POST_ID.'/likes','POST');
                                          $facebook->api('/'.$POST_ID.'/comments','POST',array('message' => $comment)); 
                                          // nothing executes after this statement, whole program breaks up.  

                                    }   

                                }

                            }


                        } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {

                              $echo($e);
                              $uid = NULL;
                    }
                }


         ?>    


</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you bothered turning on display_errors/error_reporting in PHP, and/or looking at the server's error logs?

Comment: Yeah, I did, I showed few Undefined Index for the posts which does'nt have a message but, nothing about the comment statement. The whole program is breaking once it reaches the post comment statement.